# Function name must be a string

Tags: php, function, object, methods

I get this error when I try to call `$func('something')`:

```
if(($object instanceof MyObject) && (method_exists($object, 'foo'))){
  $func = array(&$object, 'foo');

}else{
  $func = 'fallback_foo';
}

...

echo $func('something');
```

What's wrong with my code?

Obviously I cannot make $func a string because it's a method specific to a object...
but an array with the method name and object should work right?

Comment: What is `$func('something')` supposed to do?

Comment: well it should run the function / method :)

Comment: I don't think, the thing you want to achive is possible this way

Comment: I wanted to point out that this issue has been fixed since PHP 5.4.0: [Added indirect method call through array.](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.4.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`call_user_func()`](http://php.net/call_user_func) or [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array). Both support regular functions and method calls:

```
echo call_user_func($func, 'something');
```

```
echo call_user_func_array($func, array('something'));
```